# aspnet personalization

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I need help to configure app with access as default provider for aspnet personalization.

Answer (score 4):

The [ASP.NET Provider Toolkit Site](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/5/b/55bc291f-4316-4fd7-9269-dbf9edbaada8/sampleaccessproviders.vsi) provides tons of content on how to create and build your own providers (including Membership and Role Providers).  It also has a link to a fully functional Membership and Role Provider that works with Access databases.

4GuysFromRolla have a [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121456/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/010307-1.aspx) which includes one lesson about using those sample access providers.